# Can I kiil IDs of multiple users in a single query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, kill, account, drop

The command -

`SHOW PROCESSLIST;`

gives the IDs of all users currently logged in.

Suppose I have a list -

```
ID    User
1     user1
2     user2
3     user4
.     .....
N     userN
```

Now to do -

```
KILL 1;
KILL 2;
KILL 3;
......
KILL N;
```

will be a tedious job.

So can the entire job be done in a single query?

Like we have -

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 
user1@localhost, 
user2@localhost, 
user3@localhost,
................
userN@localhost;
```

Comment: if you want to kill them all, you could just restart the server?  Those aren't different users, they are different sessions (connections).

Comment: note that because sessions are closed if idle for too long, many clients automatically reconnect if they notice their session is gone.  this may be a problem for you, depending *why* you want to do this

Comment: @ysth restarting the server will mean root user will also loose the current session

Comment: @ysth also the time limit for being idle is about 24 hours from my personal experience, that's a pretty long time.

Comment: it's configurable, but I think the default is 8 hours.  anyway, because of that, there used to be the "mysql morning bug" where long running but idle processes would error because their connection had unexpectedly gone away, leading many clients to add a feature to automatically reconnect.  that feature is the issue here; it means your kills may just have temporary effect.

Comment: suppose, I need to urgently remove a certain number of users from server because of detected intended malicious activity. Then I need to quickly issue all `KILL` and `DROP USER` queries and a single line `KILL` query will be helpful

Comment: mariadb has a feature to kill all sessions for a given user.  I don't see something like that in mysql, and it sounds like you have multiple users to kill anyway.  you could look at pt-kill in the percona toolkit https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/